# Accessing Outer Table inside 2nd Level Nesting Sub Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Let's say I have,

```
select 
    (select SomColumn FROM MyInnerTable WHERE MyInnerTable.C1 = MyOuterTable.C2) AS FirstColumn
    ,(select SomColumn FROM (SELECT SomColumn FROM MyInnerTable2 WHERE MyInnerTable2.C1 = MyOuterTable.C2)) AS SecondColumn
form MyOuterTable
```

FirstColumn works but for SecondColumn its says MyOuterTable.C2 not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle (and MySQL and perhaps some other databases) limit the scope of a table to one level in a subquery.  Oops.  Can't do it that way.

In this case, you should use `LEFT JOIN` anyway.  Your query does not really need the subquery, but you can use:

```
select i.SomeColumn, i.SomeColumn as AS SecondColumn
form MyOuterTable o LEFT JOIN
     MyInnerTable i
     ON MyInnerTable.C1 = MyOuterTable.C2;
```

In more complex situations, you might find that lateral joins are what you need to solve the problem.  If you need help with that, ask a *new* question with a better example query.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT (select NAME FROM DEPARTMENT DEP WHERE DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID) AS DEPARTMENT_NAME,
(select NAME FROM (SELECT NAME FROM DEPARTMENT DEP WHERE DEP.DEPARTMENT_ID = EMP.DEPARTMENT_ID)) AS NEW_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE EMP;
```

Are you doing anything different.

Comment: . . Yes.  The OP is using Oracle.